# Reading a JMS Map Message in WSO2

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb

I am reading JMS Map Messages from WSO2 ESB. I am able to pick the message up, read all the headers, but cannot read anything in the body of the message. I have created a custom mediator, when I try the following and submit the JMS message with the MSG_FORMAT property in the header, it works fine. However when I put the property in the Map Body, WSO2 doesn't pick it up. The code below works to read the header, but will not read the Map Body

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
        String msgFormat = context.getProperty(MSG_FORMAT).toString();
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly do u mean by "Map Body" ? can you post the sample message here?

Comment: Rather than explain it myself, let me referr to the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnces/index.html A header, properties, and a body. I am able to access anything in the header and in properties using the context.getProperty() method, but I don't know how to access the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation it seems like you are trying to read the message in a custom mediator when you consume from a JMS queue.

In order to read the message, you can use the following code in the mediate method :

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
        String msgFormat = context.getProperty(MSG_FORMAT).toString();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = synCtx.getEnvelope()
....
```

Refer : https://synapse.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/synapse/MessageContext.html

Comment: Thank you, extracting the message body through the SOAP envelope worked.